# Does reallocation of a vector leads to a reallocation of the parent vector?

Tags: c++, vector

Watching at the following snippet of code. Is the output always false under all circumstance on all platforms?

```
  std::vector<std::vector<int>> array(5);
  array[0].resize(1);
  std::vector<int>* arr_start = array.data();
  int* p_start = array[0].data();

  while( p_start == array[0].data())
  {
     array[0].push_back(0);
  }

  std::cout << "Does a reallocation in a vector leads to a reallocation in the parent vector? " 
            << array.data() != arr_start;
```

Comment: The answer to your title question is no.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only certain operations on a `vector` are allowed to cause reallocation. Operations on an element of the `vector` never do so.

The fact that the element is itself a `vector` does not change this.